# Tools to diagnose BadImageFormatException thrown for System.Data assembly in production?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, desktop-application

I'm getting following exception on a production machine for a Windows desktop app:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. **File is corrupt**. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013110E)

I understand there can be multiple reasons like platform mismatch, targeted .net framework mismatch, etc. But, what tools/checks can I run on production machine to pin-point the cause?

Comment: 90% is due to x86 or x64 architecture problem. Try this first.

Comment: Hard to see how you got BadImageFormatException out of this message.  This is well beyond that exception, nothing subtle out a "File is corrupt" notification.  It is a very unusual exception, first I've ever seen it in the past 8 years.  I'd interpret it for what it tries to say, better get that hard drive replaced soon.  Ask at superuser.com for advice on how to diagnose disk problems.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the app is in 64-bits. So look into that and find an option in the advanced settings of an app pool in IIS7, named "Enable 32-Bit Applications".
[image]

After setting it to true, everything will normally work.

Note: If you want to use this in IIS6, be aware that IIS6 does not support this on a "per app pool" basis. So if you set IIS6 to 32 bit, all its app pools will run in 32 bit mode. If you want to set this on a "per app pool" basis, you will have to upgrade to IIS7.
To set IIS6 to 32 bit, do the following:

1. Open a command prompt and navigate to the
   %systemdrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts directory.
2. Enter the following command:

cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 "true"
It seems that in some cases, the "true" from the above command needs to be replaced with a 1. 
Sometimes it is also necessary to reset IIS.